# Template extends base.html but doesn't get the content of the sidebar

Tags: python, django, web

I have base_planner.html that contains a navbar and a sidebar. When I extend this base in any other template, both the navbar and sidebar are inherited, but the sidebar doesn't have any content that must be there. And I'm not getting any errors.
The only template that has the sidebar content is the home page, which is merely a ListView html page (**projectsmodel_list.html**) containing one row:
`{% extends 'app_planner\base_planner.html' %}`

Here is my **views.py** (I want TestView to inherit the sidebar content):

```
class ProjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.edit.FormMixin, generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'project_list'
    model = ProjectsModel
    form_class = ProjectsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app_planner:planner_home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['create_project_form'] = ProjectsForm()
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        project_name = form.cleaned_data['project_name']
        project_author = self.request.user
        create_project_form_item = ProjectsModel(project_name=project_name, project_author=project_author)
        create_project_form_item.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


class TestView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app_planner/test.html'
```

Here is my **urls.py**:

```
app_name = 'app_planner'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProjectListView.as_view(), name='planner_home'),
    path('test/', views.TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
]
```

Here is the body of my **base_planner.html**:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <nav id='navbar' class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a id='logo' class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'app_planner:planner_home' %}"><h3><b><span style="color:#FC5E5E;">Savvy</span> Planner</b></h3></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <div class="navbar-center">
                        <a id='projects_board' class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'app_planner:planner_home' %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'app_planner:planner_home' %}">Projects & Tasks</a>
                        <a id='analytics' class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'app_planner:analytics' %}active{% endif %}" href="#">Analytics</a>
                        <a id='analytics' class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'app_planner:test' %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'app_planner:test' %}">Test</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-right">
                        <a id='notifications' class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="{% static 'notifications_empty.svg' %}"></a>
                        <a id='logout' class="nav-link" href="{% url 'app_planner:logout' %}" class="btn btn-simple"><img src="{% static 'logout.svg' %}" width="20" height="20"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
         </nav>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class='row' style="font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; padding-bottom: 25px;">
                <div class='col-sm-6' style="height: 60px; width: 60px; border-radius: 16px; background-color: #FC5E5E;"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: fit-content;">
                    <p><span style='font-size:25px'><b>Awesome Team</span><br>
                       <span style='color:#888B94'>Workspace</span></b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class='sidebar_projects' style="border-top: solid 2px #E3E4E9; margin-left: -10px;">
                <br>
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class='row project_form'>
                        {% for field in create_project_form %}
                            <div class='col-sm-4' style='align-items:center; display: flex;'>{{ field.label }}</div>
                            <div class='col-sm-4'>{{ field }}</div>
                            <div class='col-sm-4' style='align-items:center; display: flex;'><button id='add_project' type="submit" style='background:white;border:0px;'><img src="{% static 'plus_button.svg' %}"></button></div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="row">
                    {% for project in project_list %}
                        <div class='col-sm-12 single_project'><a href="{% url 'app_planner:project_detail'  pk=project.pk %}"><span style='color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);'>__</span>{{ project.project_name }}</a></div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='content'>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Here is my **test.html**:

```
{% extends 'app_planner/base_planner.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Check the sidebar</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried changing the templates, adding content of ProjectListView to other views, and creating a separate sidebar.html and using {% include 'app_planner/sidebar.html %} in {% block sidebar %} in base_planner.html calling {% super.sidebar %} in other templates, but nothing worked. I keep seeing an empty sidebar.
This is my first time facing such an issue as {% extend %} has always worked correctly for me. I can't understand where the mistake is.

Comment: You're giving `TestView` a template, which it is inheriting, but no context with which to fill it, unless there is more to `TestView` than you are showing.  See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) or [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.extra_context).

Comment: @raphael, you're right! Haha, I was so concentrated on html templates that completely forgot about the view!

Answer (score 1):

Raphael gave me a great idea. Really, I merely forgot to give my TestView the content to show. This one works great, thanks!

```
class TestView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app_planner/test.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        project_list_view = ProjectListView()
        project_list_view.request = self.request
        project_list_view.object_list = project_list_view.get_queryset()
        project_list = project_list_view.get_context_data()['project_list']
        context['project_list'] = project_list
        return context
```